# find good buffer library in c

Tags: c, buffer

We are on designing a software in C(just C) need buffer structure in some part of that.
But I do know how to choose a good one?
Actually our program is open source and we need an open source and efficient buffer and queue library in C to implement this part.
Thanks for your helps.

Comment: A buffer? That's pretty vague... What will you do with it?

Comment: What kind of buffer?  What does it need to do?

Comment: Flagged for removal. Asking a question should not require the person to whom your asking it to ask you several more questions back.

Comment: @tbert: Why not just close-vote? I don't see why mods should be bothered with this. Also, let's be nice to the newbies.

Comment: @tbert: That's not what flags are for.

Comment: exactly. but you can flag this chat in the comment as off-topic :)

Comment: @NiklasB. 1) I see nothing in the UI presented to me which is anything close to "vote to close this question". 2) I am being nice to the newbies, by telling them why I'm asking for the question to be removed, rather than just leave them hanging, thus breeding a better generation who won't drive me to murder when they become my coworkers.

Comment: @tbert: Sorry, I don't think you have the necessary privilege yet. Still, I don't think this question fulfills the conditions to be flagged. In contrary to how you seem to assess the situation, I think the question *is* in fact salvageable through editing. Also, the sentence "Asking a question should not require the person to whom your asking it to ask you several more questions back" doesn't reflect the actual situation here on SO: Often we try to help authors to help us help them.

Comment: @tbert: we appreciate that you find innovative ways of abusing SO functionality... but if you want to help, please follow the rules

Comment: @tbert Why dont you just calm down. If the person who can answer this question is not you should not offend you to flag the question. The right person did just not yet respond.

Comment: @NiklasB. The asker is free to edit it, and I'll retract any objections. However, I don't hold out great hope that, given the muddled nature of what's being asked, that they understand how to concisely and accurately convey what, exaclty, is the gap in their knowledge that needs to be filled.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath if I'm not using it correctly, I'll stop flagging for that.

Comment: @Matthias AAARRGHHG! tbert smash!!! I am calm; if I wasn't, I wouldn't post here, but somewhere more cathartic.

Comment: I dont understand why my question faced this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this container library :

https://github.com/jacob-navia/ccl

its from eccentric genius jacob navia (if you are not regular at comp.lang.c you will not understand it). But the thing is the library is quiet efficient and unusually "EXCELLENT" manual. The Documentation will surely buy c coders.

It has most common data structures like lists/queues/deques/circular linked lists etc/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [libevent](http://libevent.org/). The newer version comes with a buffer interface suitable for the event framework that libevent provides. From their web page:

> Libevent additionally provides a sophisticated framework for buffered network IO, with support for sockets, filters, rate-limiting, SSL, zero-copy file transmission, and IOCP. Libevent includes support for several useful protocols, including DNS, HTTP, and a minimal RPC framework.